# Маска номера телефона

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как написать функцию для инпута, чтобы был ввод номера номера телефона вот такого формата:

```
+38(_ _ _)_ _ _ - _ _ - _ _
```

Подключена библиотека *JQuery*. Нашел плагин *jquery.inputmask-multi.min.js*, но не пойму что и как и где писать.

Comment: Минус я вам поставил за вопрос. Потому что не видно, чтобы вы пытались самостоятельно решить данную задачу(где ваш код). Всего вам доброго!

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov интересный подход: поставлю минус потому что вы не старались, но напишу решение чтобы срубить плюсиков в репутацию.

Comment: @websnap Здравствуйте! Мое решение верное, как мне кажется. Я потратил на него время. Я сделал даже больше, а именно: написал корректный `pattern`. Я поставил минус вопросу и написал комментарий, почему я это сделал. Все это я сделал в весьма доброжелательной манере. Ваше недовольство удивительно для меня. Еще более удивителен ваш минус за мой ответ. Всех вам благ!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
/*
    jQuery Masked Input Plugin
    Copyright (c) 2007 - 2015 Josh Bush (digitalbush.com)
    Licensed under the MIT license (http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#license)
    Version: 1.4.1
*/
!function(a){"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["jquery"],a):a("object"==typeof exports?require("jquery"):jQuery)}(function(a){var b,c=navigator.userAgent,d=/iphone/i.test(c),e=/chrome/i.test(c),f=/android/i.test(c);a.mask={definitions:{9:"[0-9]",a:"[A-Za-z]","*":"[A-Za-z0-9]"},autoclear:!0,dataName:"rawMaskFn",placeholder:"_"},a.fn.extend({caret:function(a,b){var c;if(0!==this.length&&!this.is(":hidden"))return"number"==typeof a?(b="number"==typeof b?b:a,this.each(function(){this.setSelectionRange?this.setSelectionRange(a,b):this.createTextRange&&(c=this.createTextRange(),c.collapse(!0),c.moveEnd("character",b),c.moveStart("character",a),c.select())})):(this[0].setSelectionRange?(a=this[0].selectionStart,b=this[0].selectionEnd):document.selection&&document.selection.createRange&&(c=document.selection.createRange(),a=0-c.duplicate().moveStart("character",-1e5),b=a+c.text.length),{begin:a,end:b})},unmask:function(){return this.trigger("unmask")},mask:function(c,g){var h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o;if(!c&&this.length>0){h=a(this[0]);var p=h.data(a.mask.dataName);return p?p():void 0}return g=a.extend({autoclear:a.mask.autoclear,placeholder:a.mask.placeholder,completed:null},g),i=a.mask.definitions,j=[],k=n=c.length,l=null,a.each(c.split(""),function(a,b){"?"==b?(n--,k=a):i[b]?(j.push(new RegExp(i[b])),null===l&&(l=j.length-1),k>a&&(m=j.length-1)):j.push(null)}),this.trigger("unmask").each(function(){function h(){if(g.completed){for(var a=l;m>=a;a++)if(j[a]&&C[a]===p(a))return;g.completed.call(B)}}function p(a){return g.placeholder.charAt(a<g.placeholder.length?a:0)}function q(a){for(;++a<n&&!j[a];);return a}function r(a){for(;--a>=0&&!j[a];);return a}function s(a,b){var c,d;if(!(0>a)){for(c=a,d=q(b);n>c;c++)if(j[c]){if(!(n>d&&j[c].test(C[d])))break;C[c]=C[d],C[d]=p(d),d=q(d)}z(),B.caret(Math.max(l,a))}}function t(a){var b,c,d,e;for(b=a,c=p(a);n>b;b++)if(j[b]){if(d=q(b),e=C[b],C[b]=c,!(n>d&&j[d].test(e)))break;c=e}}function u(){var a=B.val(),b=B.caret();if(o&&o.length&&o.length>a.length){for(A(!0);b.begin>0&&!j[b.begin-1];)b.begin--;if(0===b.begin)for(;b.begin<l&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}else{for(A(!0);b.begin<n&&!j[b.begin];)b.begin++;B.caret(b.begin,b.begin)}h()}function v(){A(),B.val()!=E&&B.change()}function w(a){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var b,c,e,f=a.which||a.keyCode;o=B.val(),8===f||46===f||d&&127===f?(b=B.caret(),c=b.begin,e=b.end,e-c===0&&(c=46!==f?r(c):e=q(c-1),e=46===f?q(e):e),y(c,e),s(c,e-1),a.preventDefault()):13===f?v.call(this,a):27===f&&(B.val(E),B.caret(0,A()),a.preventDefault())}}function x(b){if(!B.prop("readonly")){var c,d,e,g=b.which||b.keyCode,i=B.caret();if(!(b.ctrlKey||b.altKey||b.metaKey||32>g)&&g&&13!==g){if(i.end-i.begin!==0&&(y(i.begin,i.end),s(i.begin,i.end-1)),c=q(i.begin-1),n>c&&(d=String.fromCharCode(g),j[c].test(d))){if(t(c),C[c]=d,z(),e=q(c),f){var k=function(){a.proxy(a.fn.caret,B,e)()};setTimeout(k,0)}else B.caret(e);i.begin<=m&&h()}b.preventDefault()}}}function y(a,b){var c;for(c=a;b>c&&n>c;c++)j[c]&&(C[c]=p(c))}function z(){B.val(C.join(""))}function A(a){var b,c,d,e=B.val(),f=-1;for(b=0,d=0;n>b;b++)if(j[b]){for(C[b]=p(b);d++<e.length;)if(c=e.charAt(d-1),j[b].test(c)){C[b]=c,f=b;break}if(d>e.length){y(b+1,n);break}}else C[b]===e.charAt(d)&&d++,k>b&&(f=b);return a?z():k>f+1?g.autoclear||C.join("")===D?(B.val()&&B.val(""),y(0,n)):z():(z(),B.val(B.val().substring(0,f+1))),k?b:l}var B=a(this),C=a.map(c.split(""),function(a,b){return"?"!=a?i[a]?p(b):a:void 0}),D=C.join(""),E=B.val();B.data(a.mask.dataName,function(){return a.map(C,function(a,b){return j[b]&&a!=p(b)?a:null}).join("")}),B.one("unmask",function(){B.off(".mask").removeData(a.mask.dataName)}).on("focus.mask",function(){if(!B.prop("readonly")){clearTimeout(b);var a;E=B.val(),a=A(),b=setTimeout(function(){B.get(0)===document.activeElement&&(z(),a==c.replace("?","").length?B.caret(0,a):B.caret(a))},10)}}).on("blur.mask",v).on("keydown.mask",w).on("keypress.mask",x).on("input.mask paste.mask",function(){B.prop("readonly")||setTimeout(function(){var a=A(!0);B.caret(a),h()},0)}),e&&f&&B.off("input.mask").on("input.mask",u),A()})}})});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#phone").mask("+3 (999) 999-9999");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Аналогичный способ для маски email не подскажите?

Answer (score 2):

Я не стал разбираться с *jquery.inputmask-**multi**.min.js*, а взял просто [Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

```js
var inputsTel = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="tel"]');

Inputmask({
  "mask": "+38(999) 999-99-99",
  showMaskOnHover: false
}).mask(inputsTel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/dependencyLibs/inputmask.dependencyLib.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>


<form action="#">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" required pattern="^\+\d{2}\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}[-]\d{2}[-]\d{2}$">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

> **inputmask.dependencyLib.min.js**
>   Подключается, чтобы работало без jQuery. Если у вас есть jQuery, можно не подключать.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью этого плагина, сделать валидацию ru номера?  "mask": "+7(999) 999-99-99"

Comment: @Бармалей, всё просто. Видите в том ответе сверху js код? Просто поменяйте +38 на +7 и всё.