# Нужно сделать валидацию форм на ввод телефона по корректной маске

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, form

Нужно самое простое решение php или js

маска типа (+380) xxx xx xx

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Маска номера телефона](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743529/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#phone').mask('(+380) 000 00 00'); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="(+380) XXX XX XX">
```